# Sending POST parameters with Postman doesn't work, but sending GET parameters does

Tags: php, postman

I'm trying to test a simple PHP page using the Chrome extension Postman. When I send URL parameters, the script works fine (for example, the variables are available in the `$_REQUEST` parameter). When I send them as `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters, the `$_REQUEST` parameter only contains the `PHPSESSID`.

The script:

```
<?php
var_export($_REQUEST);
?>
```

When I send URL parameters, `$_REQUEST` includes them:

[image: URL parameters]

But when I send them as **`POST`** variables, `$_REQUEST` doesn't include them:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't yet. It might well have been something to do with our API routing, possibly only sending over some of the parameters but not all of them? I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've just given up on it just unfortunately... :/

Comment: You say you have some routing, but really, do you? Did you try to just setup a server without any application and put a file like that (so without routing)? Also, I can see you have some headers in your POST request. Did you try removing them?

Comment: Did you try uninstalling programs that are using network? It might be one of the reason of port conflict

Comment: I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28461500/704803. I was redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS and it was causing the POST variables to be lost. When I told Postman to go directly to the HTTPS url, it worked

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I was setting the URL in Postman to be `http://`, but Apache was redirecting to `https://` and somehow the POST variables were being dropped along the way.

After I changed it to `https://`, the POST variables worked properly.

See also: *[How to send POST variable in POSTMAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445276/how-to-send-post-variable-in-postman/28461500#28461500)*

Comment: This was the issue I had as well. nginx was redirecting via 302 to https and the POST parameters were dropped on the redirect. Manually setting the URL to https:// worked.

Comment: I think this is the *bug* in Postman. Working for HTTPS and not Working for HTTP. I have seen there code generated by their functinality `Generate Code` which generated wrong code for Python Requests. 

    
    querystring = {"username":"data1","mydata":"9232"}

    payload = ""
    headers = {
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        'postman-token': "aeb70e40-c12a-f713-1d8d-596b8cf976af"
       }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

    print(response.text)

I think this is buggy.

Comment: I am getting same error but this theory not applying. its not working for both.

Comment: Thanks. This one saved my time.

Comment: thank you very much, I've been looking for a way to solve this for almost a month

Answer (score 107):

I faced the same issue in Postman and Advance REST Client both. I checked through [Fiddler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiddler_%28software%29) and found that my request payload is not converted into JSON format.

I am passing my data in Body as **x-www-form-urlencoded**:

[image]

You can fix it by using **Content-Type** as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** in request header.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Arvind, changing header to ```application/x-www-form-urlencoded``` actually works!

IMHO, this should be accepted as an answer :)

Comment: Maybe someone is facing the same issue: for me, using `localhost/something` on POSTMAN wasn't working, but after adding `/` to the end, php started getting the values from `POST` and from `php://input`. I had to use `localhost/something/` to make it work.

Comment: Yes! This fixes the issue. Actually, `PARAMS` field near `URL` sets the `GET` data not `POST` data. And the keyword `PARAMS` is always being related to `GET` and `DATA` being related to `POST` for passing the data. I think peeps at PostMan should fix this to change automatic, or add the `DATA` button automatically.

Comment: @FirstOne you should at that as an answer. I got the same problem also

Comment: @FirstOne - that worked because adding `/` at end avoided a redirect. POSTMAN loses POST parameters on a redirect.

Answer (score 26):

Simply use the `Body Tab` and enter the `post parameters` there. Note that `Body Tab` is disabled if `Get` is selected.

Answer (score 15):

Check your *content-type* in the header. I was having an issue with this sending raw JSON and my content-type as *application/json* in the Postman header.

My PHP code was seeing jack all in the request post. It wasn't until I changed the *content-type* to
*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* with the JSON in the RAW textarea and its type as JSON, did my PHP application start to see the post data. Not what I expected when dealing with raw JSON, but it’s now working for what I need.

[image: Postman POST request]

Comment: Yes, changing the body type to x-www-form-urlencoded fixed it for me

Answer (score 8):

When you send parameters by `x-www-form-urlencoded` then you need to set the header for the request as using `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: For me was to select `Body` tab and select `x-www-form-urlencoded` and below that selection you can find key/value entry where you put your POST key/value data. By the way my Postman version is 4.10.4

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the raw JSON body, try using `form-data`.

[image: Form data request]

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. To fix it I added the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I had to manually add the content type even though I also had the type of "json" in the raw post field parameters.

Answer (score 4):

An issue I had was: I didn't know that under the '*Key*' column you need to put: '**Content-Type**';  I thought this was a User Key for when it came back in the request, which it isn't.

So something as simple as that may help you. I think Postman could word that column better, because I didn't even have to read the documentation when it came to using Fiddler; whereas I did with Postman.

[image: Postman picture]

Answer (score 2):

For me, the server was expecting HTTPS requests, but I didn't specify that in the URL. The hook would reach the server, but the body would be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a version problem in Postman:

I have faced the same problem. While sending the data using the oldest version of postman.

That time I have received the empty json data in server side.
And I have fixed this problem. Once I uninstall the oldest version of postman and installed with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Laravel Request method, add your

> Accept:Application/json

to your Postman header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came here again after I created an endpoint which also would not find the given POST parameters. But the problem now was the missing forward slash... So that's another one to look out for.

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing this issue and I just added *www* in the URL, like:

https://www.your-domain.com/