# When I try to send request by postman it gives me error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, postman

When I try to send request by postman fname, lname, bio, fb_token it gives me `error{"frist_name":["The frist name field is required."]`

this is the code:

```
public function store()
{
    if(User::where('fb_id','=',\Input::get('fb_id'))->exists()) 
       {
        $user = array(
            'fb_id' => Input::get('fb_id'),
            'fb_token' => Input::get('fb_token')
        );
        if (\Auth::attempt($user)) {
            echo 'found';
        } else {
            echo 'try log in again';
        }

    }
    else {
        $validation = \Validator::make(
            Request::all(), array(
            'frist_name' => 'required|alpha',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha',
            'fb_id' => 'required|unique:user',
            'user_name' => 'required|unique:user',
            'bio' => 'max:140',
            'fb_token' => 'required|unique:user'
        ));
        $f=Request::get('frist_name');
        if ($validation->passes()) {

            $newUser = new User();
            $newUser->user_name = Request::get('user_name');
            $newUser->frist_name = Request::get('frist_name');
            $newUser->last_name = Request::get('last_name');
            $newUser->fb_id = Request::get('fb_id');
            $newUser->fb_token = Request::get('fb_token');
            $newUser->profile_pic = Request::get('profile_pic');
            $newUser->bio = Request::get('bio');
            $newUser->save();

        } else {

            $error = $validation->messages();
            return \Response::json($error);
        } }
    }
```

Comment: `frist_name`? Really?

Comment: In the request you're validating, I bet "first_name" is spelled correctly.

Comment: i corrected it ...it gets the same result :$

Comment: Please update your code to the corrected code.

Comment: by the way i gess fname is not the problem because in DB it's frist_name when i send request i call it frist name it always gives me that error                 {"frist_name":["The frist name field is required."],"last_name":["The last name field is required."],"fb_id":["The fb id field is required."],"user_name":["The user name field is required."],"fb_token":["The fb token field is required."]}

Comment: @MarwaM What is the value of `Request::all()`?

Comment: @patricus any input sent to me by json !

Comment: @MarwaM I know what it is supposed to be. Dump it and see what you're actually getting. `dd(Request::all());`

Comment: @patricus it gives me empty list like this []

Comment: @MarwaM That means your request variables are not getting through. There is something wrong with your postman request. See if anything in [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168759/sending-post-parameters-with-postman-doesnt-work-but-sending-get-parameters-do?rq=1) helps you. If not, you'll probably need to post screenshots of your postman request in order to get more help.

Comment: @ patricus thank u so much i solved the problem i added wrong header in postman when i removed it everything becomes ok ^^ thanks for ur effort..

Comment: In L5 you can/should use `Request::input` instead of `Request::get`. http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input