# Advanced REST client does not send POST data

Tags: php, json, post, advanced-rest-client

I have this simple code

```
<?php
$json = array("status" => $_POST['name']);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

and when i send POST data with `Advanced REST cliend`, allways have an empty $_POST table.
[image]

Comment: Why don't you have anything in the payload? You need to paste the json data into that section

Comment: I wrote that data `{
"name": "test"
}` and nothing changed

Comment: @dios231 php doesn't know how to natively parse json. Change  raw headers to `multipart/form-data` and change raw payload to `name=test`

Comment: still not sending POST. Btwi if i change the `$_POST` to `$_GET` it display the name althouht that i have select post option at arc

Comment: I found the answer!!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977373/5277185

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong transport method. If you want to read POST data in $_POST array you have to send it either as multipart or www form urlencoded.

To read the request body you have to use following code:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Then you can parse the JSON and transform it to object.

If you want to read the data from the request using `$_POST` array you need to set Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and send the data as:

```
param-name=param+value
```

(note that it is url encoded).