# $_REQUEST only accepts GET

Tags: php, post, get, request

I'm using $_REQUEST to get sent data to a page and page will return me some value, but right now only if i send data with **GET**, page will return me data **And I need to send request with POST method.**

This is the domain that i send request to: http://rapapp.mobi 
example request: http://rapapp.mobi/?Slides=4

I have changed request_order in php.ini to both request_oder="GP" & request_order="PG" and tried but no luck!

**Note:** 

If you send request to that domain with **GET** you will be redirected to another domain with same request but if you send request to that domain in **POST** you will be redirected to website index.

**very specific:** TCP port is open, if you send request to main domain on server both methods work. (Main domain: http://rapfarsi.com). And this problem started when i moved web files from Host to VPS.

Please help me whats going on? i need to send request with POST method

**One of my functions that will return data**

```
    add_action('init' , 'Singles');
function Singles(){

if(!isset($_REQUEST['Singles'])) return;


$limitation = (int) $_REQUEST['Singles'];

$json = array();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$args = array(
'cat' => 111,
'posts_per_page' => $limitation
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

$img = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID) );
$the_query->the_post();
$json[] = array(
'id' => get_the_ID(),
'title' => get_the_title(),
'isSingle' => in_category(111,null),
'link' => get_the_permalink(),
'image' =>  wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()))
);

}
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();

echo '{"items":'.json_encode($json).'}';

die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the fastest way to resolve this problem is to override the default `$_REQUEST` values with a manual merge of `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

At the top of your app, or in the initializer script write the follow.

```
$_REQUEST = array_merge($_GET, $_POST);
```

Some PHP Frameworks use that way.

Comment: nope its not working, i added one of my functions please help me where to add the method you gave me.

Comment: is $_POST populated?

Comment: umm, what do you mean by populated? can you give me specifics?

Comment: try var_dump($_POST)

Comment: result is : array(0) {}

Comment: plus, i sent request with $_POST

Answer (score 0):

@Claudio King

I think even PHP uses $_REQUEST to store both $_GET and $_POST array values, means whatever you can access with $_GET or $_POST, you can access the same with $_REQUEST.

means if

`$_GET['name'] = 'test'` then `$_REQUEST['name']` is also = `'test'`

and same goes with `$_POST`

`$_POST['name'] = 'test'` then `$_REQUEST['name']` is also = `'test'`

Comment: yeah, what you said is true, Whats your suggestion?

Comment: Hello Ali 
Nice to hear back from you.

how are you posting data on your page?
i think you should try to Post data with PHP Curl Request set POST data and fire a request.
and on Page open you should check for the POST variable isset or not
like isset($_POST['Slides']) and if Post data is set then you should proceed with Reverting the Data as you are sending in GET request, and if is not set then you should open the Site Page.

but why you need to Revert Data from index page of your website?
means you can use a seprate page like api.php for Reverting the API Data...

Comment: BTW you built a nice website

Comment: thanks, right now i was testing with Postman chrome addon, so i sent a simple post request to that url and worked perfectly, try it your self. god whats going on?

Comment: Hello 
Postman has some issues with POST parameter, i tested it myself.
Also Refer the URL
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168759/sending-post-parameters-with-postman-doesnt-work-but-sending-get-parameters-do

and please Try this
http://requestmaker.com/

i tested it currently and it worked.

Comment: In requestmaker.com just dont set and Header
and Delete the value text/html field
and in Request Data: use Slides=4